# How to insert sequence at specific position?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-processing, biopython

I would like to insert a specific sequence at a defined position in a FASTA formatted file for multiple sequences, where the modified sequences would be output in a single file.

I have tried the following commands:

I can print the records using the code below, but I cannot insert seq at the position. I can only export fixed record data.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import pandas as pd

output_handle2 = open("new_fasta2.fasta", "a")

records1 = SeqIO.index("file_test.fa", "fasta")
candidate_df=pd.read_csv("file_test.csv")
for i in candidate_df['refseq']:

    if i in records1:
    print(">" + records1[i].id + "_" + "\n" + records1[i].seq)
    SeqIO.write(records1[i], output_handle2, 'fasta')
```

The code below prints the record and inserted sequence for only one position (column 3).

```
temp = {}
for line in open("file_test.csv","r"):
    i, c, d = line.strip().split(',')
    temp[i] = c
    temp[i] = d

for rec in SeqIO.parse("file_test.fa", "fasta"):
    if str(rec.id) in temp.keys():
        print(">" + str(rec.id) + "_" + temp[rec.id])
        a = temp[rec.id]
        b = int(len(rec)) - int(a)
        print(str(rec.seq[:len(rec) - int(a)] + "_sequence_" + rec.seq[b:]))
```

**FASTA formatted file**

```
>NM_030649
MTVEFEECVKDSPRFRATIDEVETDVVEIEAKLDKLVKLCSGMVEAGKAYVSTSRLFVSGVRDLSQQCQGDTVISECLQRFADSLQEVVNYHMILFDQAQRSVRQQLQSFVKEDVRKFKETKKQFDKVREDLELSLVRNAQAPRHRPHEVEEATGALTLTRKCFRHLALDYVLQINVLQAKKKFEILDSMLSFMHAQSSFFQQGYSLLHQLDPYMKKLAAELDQLVIDSAVEKREMERKHAAIQQRTLLQDFSYDESKVEFDVDAPSGVVMEGYLFKRASNAFKTWNRRWFSIQNSQLVYQKKLKDALTVVVDDLRLCSVKPCEDIERRFCFEVLSPTKSCMLQADSEKLRQAWVQAVQASIASAYRESPDSCYSERLDRTASPSTSSIDSATDTRERGVKGESVLQRVQSVAGNSQCGDCGQPDPRWASINLGVLLCIECSGIHRSLGVHCSKVRSLTLDSWEPELLKLMCELGNSAVNQIYEAQCEGAGSRKPTASSSRQDKEAWIKDKYVEKKFLRKAPMAPALEAPRRWRVQKCLRPHSSPRAPTARRKVRLEPVLPCVAALSSVGTLDRKFRRDSLFCPDELDSLFSYFDAGAAGAGPRSLSSDSGLGGSSDGSSDVLAFGSGSVVDSVTEEEGAESEESSGEADGDTEAEAWGLADVRELHPGLLAHRAARARDLPALAAALAHGAEVNWADAEDEGKTPLVQAVLGGSLIVCEFLLQNGADVNQRDSRGRAPLHHATLLGRTGQVCLFLKRGADQHALDQEQRDPLAIAVQAANADIVTLLRLARMAEEMREAEAAPGPPGALAGSPTELQFRRCIQEFISLHLEES
>NM_001256456
MCGAGFGHFEWLAGGGAGQDVGRSCILVSIAGKNVMLDCGMHMGFNDDRRFPDFSYITQNGRLTDFLDCVIISHFHLDHCGALPYFSEMVGYDGPIYMTHPTQAICPILLEDYRKIAVDKKGEANFFTSQMIKDCMKKVVAVHLHQTVQVDDELEIKAYYAGHVLGAAMFQIKVGSESVVYTGDYNMTPDRHLGAAWIDKCRPNLLITESTYATTIRDSKRCRERDFLKKVHETVERGGKVLIPVFALGRAQELCILLETFWERMNLKVPIYFSTGLTEKANHYYKLFIPWTNQKIRKTFVQRNMFEFKHIKAFDRAFADNPGPMVVFATPGMLHAGQSLQIFRKWAGNEKNMVIMPGYCVQGTVGHKILSGQRKLEMEGRQVLEVKMQVEYMSFSAHADAKGIMQLVGQAEPESVLLVHGEAKKMEFLKQKIEQELRVNCYMPANGETVTLPTSPSIPVGISLGLLKREMAQGLLPEAKKPRLLHGTLIMKDSNFRLVSSEQALKELGLAEHQLRFTCRVHLHDTRKEQETALRVYSHLKSVLKDHCVQHLPDGSVTVESVLLQAAAPSEDPGTKVLLVSWTYQDEELGSFLTSLLKKGLPQAPS
```

**Positions where to insert sequence**

column 1: label 
column 2: 2nd part of label 
column 3: position

```
NM_030649   1   33
NM_030649   2   69
NM_001256456    1   91
NM_001256456    2   202
```

**custom sequence to insert** -
I have indicated a lower case sequence here to easily visualize in example below, but final sequence will be upper case.

```
sequence
```

**Example output**

```
>NM_030649_1
MTVEFEECVKDSPRFRATIDEVETDVVEIEAKLsequenceDKLVKLCSGMVEAGKAYVSTSRLFVSGVRDLSQQCQGDTVISECLQRFADSLQEVVNYHMILFDQAQRSVRQQLQSFVKEDVRKFKETKKQFDKVREDLELSLVRNAQAPRHRPHEVEEATGALTLTRKCFRHLALDYVLQINVLQAKKKFEILDSMLSFMHAQSSFFQQGYSLLHQLDPYMKKLAAELDQLVIDSAVEKREMERKHAAIQQRTLLQDFSYDESKVEFDVDAPSGVVMEGYLFKRASNAFKTWNRRWFSIQNSQLVYQKKLKDALTVVVDDLRLCSVKPCEDIERRFCFEVLSPTKSCMLQADSEKLRQAWVQAVQASIASAYRESPDSCYSERLDRTASPSTSSIDSATDTRERGVKGESVLQRVQSVAGNSQCGDCGQPDPRWASINLGVLLCIECSGIHRSLGVHCSKVRSLTLDSWEPELLKLMCELGNSAVNQIYEAQCEGAGSRKPTASSSRQDKEAWIKDKYVEKKFLRKAPMAPALEAPRRWRVQKCLRPHSSPRAPTARRKVRLEPVLPCVAALSSVGTLDRKFRRDSLFCPDELDSLFSYFDAGAAGAGPRSLSSDSGLGGSSDGSSDVLAFGSGSVVDSVTEEEGAESEESSGEADGDTEAEAWGLADVRELHPGLLAHRAARARDLPALAAALAHGAEVNWADAEDEGKTPLVQAVLGGSLIVCEFLLQNGADVNQRDSRGRAPLHHATLLGRTGQVCLFLKRGADQHALDQEQRDPLAIAVQAANADIVTLLRLARMAEEMREAEAAPGPPGALAGSPTELQFRRCIQEFISLHLEES
>NM_030649_2
MTVEFEECVKDSPRFRATIDEVETDVVEIEAKLDKLVKLCSGMVEAGKAYVSTSRLFVSGVRDLSQQCQsequenceGDTVISECLQRFADSLQEVVNYHMILFDQAQRSVRQQLQSFVKEDVRKFKETKKQFDKVREDLELSLVRNAQAPRHRPHEVEEATGALTLTRKCFRHLALDYVLQINVLQAKKKFEILDSMLSFMHAQSSFFQQGYSLLHQLDPYMKKLAAELDQLVIDSAVEKREMERKHAAIQQRTLLQDFSYDESKVEFDVDAPSGVVMEGYLFKRASNAFKTWNRRWFSIQNSQLVYQKKLKDALTVVVDDLRLCSVKPCEDIERRFCFEVLSPTKSCMLQADSEKLRQAWVQAVQASIASAYRESPDSCYSERLDRTASPSTSSIDSATDTRERGVKGESVLQRVQSVAGNSQCGDCGQPDPRWASINLGVLLCIECSGIHRSLGVHCSKVRSLTLDSWEPELLKLMCELGNSAVNQIYEAQCEGAGSRKPTASSSRQDKEAWIKDKYVEKKFLRKAPMAPALEAPRRWRVQKCLRPHSSPRAPTARRKVRLEPVLPCVAALSSVGTLDRKFRRDSLFCPDELDSLFSYFDAGAAGAGPRSLSSDSGLGGSSDGSSDVLAFGSGSVVDSVTEEEGAESEESSGEADGDTEAEAWGLADVRELHPGLLAHRAARARDLPALAAALAHGAEVNWADAEDEGKTPLVQAVLGGSLIVCEFLLQNGADVNQRDSRGRAPLHHATLLGRTGQVCLFLKRGADQHALDQEQRDPLAIAVQAANADIVTLLRLARMAEEMREAEAAPGPPGALAGSPTELQFRRCIQEFISLHLEES
>NM_001256456_1
MCGAGFGHFEWLAGGGAGQDVGRSCILVSIAGKNVMLDCGMHMGFNDDRRFPDFSYITQNGRLTDFLDCVIISHFHLDHCGALPYFSEMVGsequenceYDGPIYMTHPTQAICPILLEDYRKIAVDKKGEANFFTSQMIKDCMKKVVAVHLHQTVQVDDELEIKAYYAGHVLGAAMFQIKVGSESVVYTGDYNMTPDRHLGAAWIDKCRPNLLITESTYATTIRDSKRCRERDFLKKVHETVERGGKVLIPVFALGRAQELCILLETFWERMNLKVPIYFSTGLTEKANHYYKLFIPWTNQKIRKTFVQRNMFEFKHIKAFDRAFADNPGPMVVFATPGMLHAGQSLQIFRKWAGNEKNMVIMPGYCVQGTVGHKILSGQRKLEMEGRQVLEVKMQVEYMSFSAHADAKGIMQLVGQAEPESVLLVHGEAKKMEFLKQKIEQELRVNCYMPANGETVTLPTSPSIPVGISLGLLKREMAQGLLPEAKKPRLLHGTLIMKDSNFRLVSSEQALKELGLAEHQLRFTCRVHLHDTRKEQETALRVYSHLKSVLKDHCVQHLPDGSVTVESVLLQAAAPSEDPGTKVLLVSWTYQDEELGSFLTSLLKKGLPQAPS
>NM_001256456_2
MCGAGFGHFEWLAGGGAGQDVGRSCILVSIAGKNVMLDCGMHMGFNDDRRFPDFSYITQNGRLTDFLDCVIISHFHLDHCGALPYFSEMVGYDGPIYMTHPTQAICPILLEDYRKIAVDKKGEANFFTSQMIKDCMKKVVAVHLHQTVQVDDELEIKAYYAGHVLGAAMFQIKVGSESVVYTGDYNMTPDRHLGAAWIDKCRsequencePNLLITESTYATTIRDSKRCRERDFLKKVHETVERGGKVLIPVFALGRAQELCILLETFWERMNLKVPIYFSTGLTEKANHYYKLFIPWTNQKIRKTFVQRNMFEFKHIKAFDRAFADNPGPMVVFATPGMLHAGQSLQIFRKWAGNEKNMVIMPGYCVQGTVGHKILSGQRKLEMEGRQVLEVKMQVEYMSFSAHADAKGIMQLVGQAEPESVLLVHGEAKKMEFLKQKIEQELRVNCYMPANGETVTLPTSPSIPVGISLGLLKREMAQGLLPEAKKPRLLHGTLIMKDSNFRLVSSEQALKELGLAEHQLRFTCRVHLHDTRKEQETALRVYSHLKSVLKDHCVQHLPDGSVTVESVLLQAAAPSEDPGTKVLLVSWTYQDEELGSFLTSLLKKGLPQAPS
```

Comment: https://www.biostars.org/p/261803/  --> Change sequence in SEQIO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

second attempt:

csv file, `file_test.csv` :

```
NM_030649,   1,   33
NM_030649,   2,   69
NM_001256456,    1,  91
NM_001256456,    2,   202
```

fasta file,  `file_test.fa`             :

```
>NM_030649
MTVEFEECVKDSPRFRATIDEVETDVVEIEAKLDKLVKLCSGMVEAGKAYVSTSRLFVSGVRDLSQQCQGDTVISECLQRFADSLQEVVNYHMILFDQAQRSVRQQLQSFVKEDVRKFKETKKQFDKVREDLELSLVRNAQAPRHRPHEVEEATGALTLTRKCFRHLALDYVLQINVLQAKKKFEILDSMLSFMHAQSSFFQQGYSLLHQLDPYMKKLAAELDQLVIDSAVEKREMERKHAAIQQRTLLQDFSYDESKVEFDVDAPSGVVMEGYLFKRASNAFKTWNRRWFSIQNSQLVYQKKLKDALTVVVDDLRLCSVKPCEDIERRFCFEVLSPTKSCMLQADSEKLRQAWVQAVQASIASAYRESPDSCYSERLDRTASPSTSSIDSATDTRERGVKGESVLQRVQSVAGNSQCGDCGQPDPRWASINLGVLLCIECSGIHRSLGVHCSKVRSLTLDSWEPELLKLMCELGNSAVNQIYEAQCEGAGSRKPTASSSRQDKEAWIKDKYVEKKFLRKAPMAPALEAPRRWRVQKCLRPHSSPRAPTARRKVRLEPVLPCVAALSSVGTLDRKFRRDSLFCPDELDSLFSYFDAGAAGAGPRSLSSDSGLGGSSDGSSDVLAFGSGSVVDSVTEEEGAESEESSGEADGDTEAEAWGLADVRELHPGLLAHRAARARDLPALAAALAHGAEVNWADAEDEGKTPLVQAVLGGSLIVCEFLLQNGADVNQRDSRGRAPLHHATLLGRTGQVCLFLKRGADQHALDQEQRDPLAIAVQAANADIVTLLRLARMAEEMREAEAAPGPPGALAGSPTELQFRRCIQEFISLHLEES
>NM_001256456
MCGAGFGHFEWLAGGGAGQDVGRSCILVSIAGKNVMLDCGMHMGFNDDRRFPDFSYITQNGRLTDFLDCVIISHFHLDHCGALPYFSEMVGYDGPIYMTHPTQAICPILLEDYRKIAVDKKGEANFFTSQMIKDCMKKVVAVHLHQTVQVDDELEIKAYYAGHVLGAAMFQIKVGSESVVYTGDYNMTPDRHLGAAWIDKCRPNLLITESTYATTIRDSKRCRERDFLKKVHETVERGGKVLIPVFALGRAQELCILLETFWERMNLKVPIYFSTGLTEKANHYYKLFIPWTNQKIRKTFVQRNMFEFKHIKAFDRAFADNPGPMVVFATPGMLHAGQSLQIFRKWAGNEKNMVIMPGYCVQGTVGHKILSGQRKLEMEGRQVLEVKMQVEYMSFSAHADAKGIMQLVGQAEPESVLLVHGEAKKMEFLKQKIEQELRVNCYMPANGETVTLPTSPSIPVGISLGLLKREMAQGLLPEAKKPRLLHGTLIMKDSNFRLVSSEQALKELGLAEHQLRFTCRVHLHDTRKEQETALRVYSHLKSVLKDHCVQHLPDGSVTVESVLLQAAAPSEDPGTKVLLVSWTYQDEELGSFLTSLLKKGLPQAPS
```

my code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

from Bio.Seq import Seq


# import pandas as pd

sequence = "_sequence_"

temp = {}
for line in open("file_test.csv","r"):
    # print(line)
    i, c, d = line.strip().replace(" ", "").split(',')
    
    # print(i,c,d, '\n\n')
    temp[i+'_'+c] = d
    # temp[i] = d # ------> removed
    
    
print(temp,'\n')

with open("result.fa", "w") as handle:
        
    for label in temp.keys():
        # print(label,'  ',label.rsplit('_', 1)[0])
        if label.rsplit('_', 1)[0] in [rec.id for rec in SeqIO.parse("file_test.fa", "fasta")]:
            for rec in SeqIO.parse("file_test.fa", "fasta"):
                if rec.id == label.rsplit('_', 1)[0]:
                    
                    print('record :')
                    print(rec)
                    print('..................')
                    
                    print(label, len(rec.seq), len(sequence))
                    
                    print(rec.seq[:int(temp[label])] + sequence 
                                          + rec.seq[int(temp[label]):])
                    
                    rec.id = label
                    
                    rec.name = ''
                    
                    rec.description = ''
                    
                    rec.seq = Seq(str(rec.seq[:int(temp[label])] + sequence
                                                      + rec.seq[int(temp[label]):]))
                    
                    print(len(rec.seq), len(sequence),'\n')

                    SeqIO.write(rec, handle, "fasta")
                    print('_______________________')
```

output, printed not saved:

```
{'NM_030649_1': '33', 'NM_030649_2': '69', 'NM_001256456_1': '91', 'NM_001256456_2': '202'} 

record :
ID: NM_030649
Name: NM_030649
Description: NM_030649
Number of features: 0
Seq('MTVEFEECVKDSPRFRATIDEVETDVVEIEAKLDKLVKLCSGMVEAGKAYVSTS...EES')
..................
NM_030649_1 834 10
MTVEFEECVKDSPRFRATIDEVETDVVEIEAKL_sequence_DKLVKLCSGMVEAGKAYVSTSRLFVSGVRDLSQQCQGDTVISECLQRFADSLQEVVNYHMILFDQAQRSVRQQLQSFVKEDVRKFKETKKQFDKVREDLELSLVRNAQAPRHRPHEVEEATGALTLTRKCFRHLALDYVLQINVLQAKKKFEILDSMLSFMHAQSSFFQQGYSLLHQLDPYMKKLAAELDQLVIDSAVEKREMERKHAAIQQRTLLQDFSYDESKVEFDVDAPSGVVMEGYLFKRASNAFKTWNRRWFSIQNSQLVYQKKLKDALTVVVDDLRLCSVKPCEDIERRFCFEVLSPTKSCMLQADSEKLRQAWVQAVQASIASAYRESPDSCYSERLDRTASPSTSSIDSATDTRERGVKGESVLQRVQSVAGNSQCGDCGQPDPRWASINLGVLLCIECSGIHRSLGVHCSKVRSLTLDSWEPELLKLMCELGNSAVNQIYEAQCEGAGSRKPTASSSRQDKEAWIKDKYVEKKFLRKAPMAPALEAPRRWRVQKCLRPHSSPRAPTARRKVRLEPVLPCVAALSSVGTLDRKFRRDSLFCPDELDSLFSYFDAGAAGAGPRSLSSDSGLGGSSDGSSDVLAFGSGSVVDSVTEEEGAESEESSGEADGDTEAEAWGLADVRELHPGLLAHRAARARDLPALAAALAHGAEVNWADAEDEGKTPLVQAVLGGSLIVCEFLLQNGADVNQRDSRGRAPLHHATLLGRTGQVCLFLKRGADQHALDQEQRDPLAIAVQAANADIVTLLRLARMAEEMREAEAAPGPPGALAGSPTELQFRRCIQEFISLHLEES
844 10 

_______________________
record :
ID: NM_030649
Name: NM_030649
Description: NM_030649
Number of features: 0
Seq('MTVEFEECVKDSPRFRATIDEVETDVVEIEAKLDKLVKLCSGMVEAGKAYVSTS...EES')
..................
NM_030649_2 834 10
MTVEFEECVKDSPRFRATIDEVETDVVEIEAKLDKLVKLCSGMVEAGKAYVSTSRLFVSGVRDLSQQCQ_sequence_GDTVISECLQRFADSLQEVVNYHMILFDQAQRSVRQQLQSFVKEDVRKFKETKKQFDKVREDLELSLVRNAQAPRHRPHEVEEATGALTLTRKCFRHLALDYVLQINVLQAKKKFEILDSMLSFMHAQSSFFQQGYSLLHQLDPYMKKLAAELDQLVIDSAVEKREMERKHAAIQQRTLLQDFSYDESKVEFDVDAPSGVVMEGYLFKRASNAFKTWNRRWFSIQNSQLVYQKKLKDALTVVVDDLRLCSVKPCEDIERRFCFEVLSPTKSCMLQADSEKLRQAWVQAVQASIASAYRESPDSCYSERLDRTASPSTSSIDSATDTRERGVKGESVLQRVQSVAGNSQCGDCGQPDPRWASINLGVLLCIECSGIHRSLGVHCSKVRSLTLDSWEPELLKLMCELGNSAVNQIYEAQCEGAGSRKPTASSSRQDKEAWIKDKYVEKKFLRKAPMAPALEAPRRWRVQKCLRPHSSPRAPTARRKVRLEPVLPCVAALSSVGTLDRKFRRDSLFCPDELDSLFSYFDAGAAGAGPRSLSSDSGLGGSSDGSSDVLAFGSGSVVDSVTEEEGAESEESSGEADGDTEAEAWGLADVRELHPGLLAHRAARARDLPALAAALAHGAEVNWADAEDEGKTPLVQAVLGGSLIVCEFLLQNGADVNQRDSRGRAPLHHATLLGRTGQVCLFLKRGADQHALDQEQRDPLAIAVQAANADIVTLLRLARMAEEMREAEAAPGPPGALAGSPTELQFRRCIQEFISLHLEES
844 10 

_______________________
record :
ID: NM_001256456
Name: NM_001256456
Description: NM_001256456
Number of features: 0
Seq('MCGAGFGHFEWLAGGGAGQDVGRSCILVSIAGKNVMLDCGMHMGFNDDRRFPDF...APS')
..................
NM_001256456_1 606 10
MCGAGFGHFEWLAGGGAGQDVGRSCILVSIAGKNVMLDCGMHMGFNDDRRFPDFSYITQNGRLTDFLDCVIISHFHLDHCGALPYFSEMVG_sequence_YDGPIYMTHPTQAICPILLEDYRKIAVDKKGEANFFTSQMIKDCMKKVVAVHLHQTVQVDDELEIKAYYAGHVLGAAMFQIKVGSESVVYTGDYNMTPDRHLGAAWIDKCRPNLLITESTYATTIRDSKRCRERDFLKKVHETVERGGKVLIPVFALGRAQELCILLETFWERMNLKVPIYFSTGLTEKANHYYKLFIPWTNQKIRKTFVQRNMFEFKHIKAFDRAFADNPGPMVVFATPGMLHAGQSLQIFRKWAGNEKNMVIMPGYCVQGTVGHKILSGQRKLEMEGRQVLEVKMQVEYMSFSAHADAKGIMQLVGQAEPESVLLVHGEAKKMEFLKQKIEQELRVNCYMPANGETVTLPTSPSIPVGISLGLLKREMAQGLLPEAKKPRLLHGTLIMKDSNFRLVSSEQALKELGLAEHQLRFTCRVHLHDTRKEQETALRVYSHLKSVLKDHCVQHLPDGSVTVESVLLQAAAPSEDPGTKVLLVSWTYQDEELGSFLTSLLKKGLPQAPS
616 10 

_______________________
record :
ID: NM_001256456
Name: NM_001256456
Description: NM_001256456
Number of features: 0
Seq('MCGAGFGHFEWLAGGGAGQDVGRSCILVSIAGKNVMLDCGMHMGFNDDRRFPDF...APS')
..................
NM_001256456_2 606 10
MCGAGFGHFEWLAGGGAGQDVGRSCILVSIAGKNVMLDCGMHMGFNDDRRFPDFSYITQNGRLTDFLDCVIISHFHLDHCGALPYFSEMVGYDGPIYMTHPTQAICPILLEDYRKIAVDKKGEANFFTSQMIKDCMKKVVAVHLHQTVQVDDELEIKAYYAGHVLGAAMFQIKVGSESVVYTGDYNMTPDRHLGAAWIDKCR_sequence_PNLLITESTYATTIRDSKRCRERDFLKKVHETVERGGKVLIPVFALGRAQELCILLETFWERMNLKVPIYFSTGLTEKANHYYKLFIPWTNQKIRKTFVQRNMFEFKHIKAFDRAFADNPGPMVVFATPGMLHAGQSLQIFRKWAGNEKNMVIMPGYCVQGTVGHKILSGQRKLEMEGRQVLEVKMQVEYMSFSAHADAKGIMQLVGQAEPESVLLVHGEAKKMEFLKQKIEQELRVNCYMPANGETVTLPTSPSIPVGISLGLLKREMAQGLLPEAKKPRLLHGTLIMKDSNFRLVSSEQALKELGLAEHQLRFTCRVHLHDTRKEQETALRVYSHLKSVLKDHCVQHLPDGSVTVESVLLQAAAPSEDPGTKVLLVSWTYQDEELGSFLTSLLKKGLPQAPS
616 10 

_______________________
```

fasta file saved, as `result.fa` :

```
>NM_030649_1
MTVEFEECVKDSPRFRATIDEVETDVVEIEAKL_sequence_DKLVKLCSGMVEAGKAY
VSTSRLFVSGVRDLSQQCQGDTVISECLQRFADSLQEVVNYHMILFDQAQRSVRQQLQSF
VKEDVRKFKETKKQFDKVREDLELSLVRNAQAPRHRPHEVEEATGALTLTRKCFRHLALD
YVLQINVLQAKKKFEILDSMLSFMHAQSSFFQQGYSLLHQLDPYMKKLAAELDQLVIDSA
VEKREMERKHAAIQQRTLLQDFSYDESKVEFDVDAPSGVVMEGYLFKRASNAFKTWNRRW
FSIQNSQLVYQKKLKDALTVVVDDLRLCSVKPCEDIERRFCFEVLSPTKSCMLQADSEKL
RQAWVQAVQASIASAYRESPDSCYSERLDRTASPSTSSIDSATDTRERGVKGESVLQRVQ
SVAGNSQCGDCGQPDPRWASINLGVLLCIECSGIHRSLGVHCSKVRSLTLDSWEPELLKL
MCELGNSAVNQIYEAQCEGAGSRKPTASSSRQDKEAWIKDKYVEKKFLRKAPMAPALEAP
RRWRVQKCLRPHSSPRAPTARRKVRLEPVLPCVAALSSVGTLDRKFRRDSLFCPDELDSL
FSYFDAGAAGAGPRSLSSDSGLGGSSDGSSDVLAFGSGSVVDSVTEEEGAESEESSGEAD
GDTEAEAWGLADVRELHPGLLAHRAARARDLPALAAALAHGAEVNWADAEDEGKTPLVQA
VLGGSLIVCEFLLQNGADVNQRDSRGRAPLHHATLLGRTGQVCLFLKRGADQHALDQEQR
DPLAIAVQAANADIVTLLRLARMAEEMREAEAAPGPPGALAGSPTELQFRRCIQEFISLH
LEES
>NM_030649_2
MTVEFEECVKDSPRFRATIDEVETDVVEIEAKLDKLVKLCSGMVEAGKAYVSTSRLFVSG
VRDLSQQCQ_sequence_GDTVISECLQRFADSLQEVVNYHMILFDQAQRSVRQQLQSF
VKEDVRKFKETKKQFDKVREDLELSLVRNAQAPRHRPHEVEEATGALTLTRKCFRHLALD
YVLQINVLQAKKKFEILDSMLSFMHAQSSFFQQGYSLLHQLDPYMKKLAAELDQLVIDSA
VEKREMERKHAAIQQRTLLQDFSYDESKVEFDVDAPSGVVMEGYLFKRASNAFKTWNRRW
FSIQNSQLVYQKKLKDALTVVVDDLRLCSVKPCEDIERRFCFEVLSPTKSCMLQADSEKL
RQAWVQAVQASIASAYRESPDSCYSERLDRTASPSTSSIDSATDTRERGVKGESVLQRVQ
SVAGNSQCGDCGQPDPRWASINLGVLLCIECSGIHRSLGVHCSKVRSLTLDSWEPELLKL
MCELGNSAVNQIYEAQCEGAGSRKPTASSSRQDKEAWIKDKYVEKKFLRKAPMAPALEAP
RRWRVQKCLRPHSSPRAPTARRKVRLEPVLPCVAALSSVGTLDRKFRRDSLFCPDELDSL
FSYFDAGAAGAGPRSLSSDSGLGGSSDGSSDVLAFGSGSVVDSVTEEEGAESEESSGEAD
GDTEAEAWGLADVRELHPGLLAHRAARARDLPALAAALAHGAEVNWADAEDEGKTPLVQA
VLGGSLIVCEFLLQNGADVNQRDSRGRAPLHHATLLGRTGQVCLFLKRGADQHALDQEQR
DPLAIAVQAANADIVTLLRLARMAEEMREAEAAPGPPGALAGSPTELQFRRCIQEFISLH
LEES
>NM_001256456_1
MCGAGFGHFEWLAGGGAGQDVGRSCILVSIAGKNVMLDCGMHMGFNDDRRFPDFSYITQN
GRLTDFLDCVIISHFHLDHCGALPYFSEMVG_sequence_YDGPIYMTHPTQAICPILL
EDYRKIAVDKKGEANFFTSQMIKDCMKKVVAVHLHQTVQVDDELEIKAYYAGHVLGAAMF
QIKVGSESVVYTGDYNMTPDRHLGAAWIDKCRPNLLITESTYATTIRDSKRCRERDFLKK
VHETVERGGKVLIPVFALGRAQELCILLETFWERMNLKVPIYFSTGLTEKANHYYKLFIP
WTNQKIRKTFVQRNMFEFKHIKAFDRAFADNPGPMVVFATPGMLHAGQSLQIFRKWAGNE
KNMVIMPGYCVQGTVGHKILSGQRKLEMEGRQVLEVKMQVEYMSFSAHADAKGIMQLVGQ
AEPESVLLVHGEAKKMEFLKQKIEQELRVNCYMPANGETVTLPTSPSIPVGISLGLLKRE
MAQGLLPEAKKPRLLHGTLIMKDSNFRLVSSEQALKELGLAEHQLRFTCRVHLHDTRKEQ
ETALRVYSHLKSVLKDHCVQHLPDGSVTVESVLLQAAAPSEDPGTKVLLVSWTYQDEELG
SFLTSLLKKGLPQAPS
>NM_001256456_2
MCGAGFGHFEWLAGGGAGQDVGRSCILVSIAGKNVMLDCGMHMGFNDDRRFPDFSYITQN
GRLTDFLDCVIISHFHLDHCGALPYFSEMVGYDGPIYMTHPTQAICPILLEDYRKIAVDK
KGEANFFTSQMIKDCMKKVVAVHLHQTVQVDDELEIKAYYAGHVLGAAMFQIKVGSESVV
YTGDYNMTPDRHLGAAWIDKCR_sequence_PNLLITESTYATTIRDSKRCRERDFLKK
VHETVERGGKVLIPVFALGRAQELCILLETFWERMNLKVPIYFSTGLTEKANHYYKLFIP
WTNQKIRKTFVQRNMFEFKHIKAFDRAFADNPGPMVVFATPGMLHAGQSLQIFRKWAGNE
KNMVIMPGYCVQGTVGHKILSGQRKLEMEGRQVLEVKMQVEYMSFSAHADAKGIMQLVGQ
AEPESVLLVHGEAKKMEFLKQKIEQELRVNCYMPANGETVTLPTSPSIPVGISLGLLKRE
MAQGLLPEAKKPRLLHGTLIMKDSNFRLVSSEQALKELGLAEHQLRFTCRVHLHDTRKEQ
ETALRVYSHLKSVLKDHCVQHLPDGSVTVESVLLQAAAPSEDPGTKVLLVSWTYQDEELG
SFLTSLLKKGLPQAPS
```

Comment: Your script is mostly correct. I can modify script to generate fasta format output (>NM_030649_2 834 10). However, I am not sure how to write the output to a file. thanks

Comment: See  my other answer, open a file in w mode, use SeqIO.write

Comment: I can print the output by placing commands "with open("result.fa", "w") as handle:" before "for label in temp.keys():". And "SeqIO.write(rec, handle, "fasta")" at the end. However, the unique refseq info is not saved to the file. Correct: (>NM_030649_1 834 10), incorrect: (>NM_030649)

Comment: have a look at the edited code, familiarize yourself with the seqrecord object, that is rec in your/mine code (for rec in SeqIO.parse("file_test.fa", "fasta"):). I printed it out. Each record as a Seq but an ID, a name and a descritption too.  Try to add for rec in SeqIO.parse("result.fa", "fasta"):
    print(rec) at the end of the code and see what you get. Not sure if there is anator way to save only the ID of a sequence

Comment: @slives see here https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqRecord, I am sorry I rejected your edit it was the right way to save it, I forgot about seqrecord  and was easier to me to rewrite it to get your desidered answer

Answer (score 0):

I do not have your entire code, so tried to figure out an example answering your question: "How to insert sequence at specific position?"

My position its specific being half the sequence lenght (not at a given index,
but the problem was not there).

input fasta `fasta2.fa` :

```
>NM_030649
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
>NM_001256456
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

my code example :

```
from Bio import SeqIO

from Bio.Seq import Seq



with open("result.fa", "w") as handle:
    for rec in SeqIO.parse("fasta2.fa", "fasta"):
        print(rec.seq)
        print('before : ',len(rec.seq))
        
        str_rec_seq = str(rec.seq)
        
        rec.seq = Seq(str_rec_seq[:len(rec.seq)//2]+'P'*10+
                      str_rec_seq[len(rec.seq)-len(rec.seq)//2-len(str_rec_seq)%2:])
        
        print('after : ',len(rec.seq))
        
        SeqIO.write(rec, handle, "fasta")
```

output fasta `result.fa`

```
>NM_030649
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPPPPPPPPPPAAAAAACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
CCCCCCC
>NM_001256456
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTPPPPPPPPPPTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

Comment: The problem I am encountering is that I need to use information from 3 columns. First column is the refseq ID, the second column can be used for the output label (e.g. NM_030649_1, NM_030649_2), and the third column indicates the specific position to insert the sequence. If there was only one refseq ID my original code would work. My example output above shows what format output I am looking for. Hopefully this clarified my question.